# Action Bar Sherlock 4 title text colour - where am I going wrong?

Tags: java, android, actionbarsherlock

I'm having difficulty making my Action Bar title text colour go white. Having followed examples I believe my code is correct, however the text appears black.

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

```
<resources>
    <style name="Theme.MyApp" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light">
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.MyApp.ActionBar</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.MyApp.ActionBar</item>
        <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/Widget.MyApp.TitleTextStyle</item>
        <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/Widget.MyApp.TitleTextStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Widget.MyApp.ActionBar" parent="Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar">
        <item name="background">@drawable/gradient_blue</item>
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/gradient_blue</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Widget.MyApp.TitleTextStyle" parent="Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar">
        <item name="titleTextStyle">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@color/white</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use the following, just customize the `actionBarStyle` property:

```
<resources>
    <style name="Theme.MyApp" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light">
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.MyApp.ActionBar</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.MyApp.ActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Widget.MyApp.ActionBar" parent="Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar">
        <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/Widget.MyApp.TitleTextStyle</item>
        <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/Widget.MyApp.TitleTextStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Widget.MyApp.TitleTextStyle" parent="TextAppearance.Sherlock.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

and you can customize `textSize` of title too.

Comment: I have copied your suggestion word for word and it doesn't appear to work either. Now I'm beginning to wonder if it's something wrong somewhere else in my app.

Comment: I use this method to change the fontSize parameter, I think textColor should change in the same way.

Comment: @BigJoe This code only worked for pre-ICS phones.  In order to work in 4.0+, use my edits (see the line containing `android:titleTextStyle`).

Answer (score 1):

You should set the text color and other text property's within the text style.

```
<style name="Widget.MyApp.TitleTextStyle" parent="Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
</style>
```