# Android ActionBarSherlock Changing Text Style / Size / Color

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I would like to change the text style/ font size /font colour for my actionbarsherlock action bar. I will show my attempt below, but it just shows an error "`error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'android:textColor' with value '@color/black').`" and "`error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'android:textSize' with value '@dimen/20dp').`" Can somebody show me how it is done?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<style name="ABSTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light.ForceOverflow">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ABSTheme.ActionBar</item>
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/ABSTheme.ActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="ABSTheme.ActionBar" parent="Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar.Solid">
    <item name="android:displayOptions">showHome|useLogo</item>
    <item name="displayOptions">showHome|useLogo</item>
    <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/ABSTheme.ActionBar.TextAppearance</item>
</style>

<style name="ABSTheme.ActionBar.TextAppearance" parent="@style/TextAppearance.Sherlock.Widget.ActionBar.Menu">
      <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/20dp</item>
      <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
 </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: Try putting 20dp instead of "@dimen/20dp" and #000000 instead of "@color/black", see if that works.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ActionBar text color](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5861661/actionbar-text-color)

Comment: its not a duplicate. My title is written Changing Text Style / Size / Color

Comment: The steps aren't much different for changing these other characteristics. But you are in luck, here's another that explicitly covers style, color, and size: [Action Bar Sherlock 4 title text colour - where am I going wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10466796/1267661)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**wdziernia** is right.  For dimension you can just do 20dp and for color you can specify a hex color like #ffffff.

If you want to use predefined values in other xml files you can create your own by creating an xml file in values/colors.xml that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<color name="black">#ffffff</color>
</resources>
```

Then in your style xml file you can reference @color/black.  In this case you can just use the color black that android has built-in: `@android:color/black` instead of `@color/black` (the `@android:` uses android built-ins.

You can do a similar thing specifying dimensions by name in a separate xml file as well.