# How do you change the action bar text color without Sherlock?

Tags: java, android, text, colors, android-actionbar

I don't want to use the Sherlock action bar, but I do want to change the text color. I know how to change the actual text

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.setTitle("Whatever");
```

but I don't know how to change the color. I have also tried this:

```
    <style name="ActionBar.Solid.Example" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/ab_background_textured_example</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundStacked">@drawable/ab_stacked_solid_example</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundSplit">@drawable/ab_background_textured_example</item>
    <item name="android:progressBarStyle">@style/ProgressBar.Example</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
   </style>
```

From the "Android Holo Colors Generator", I added the line

```
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
```

but it didn't do anything.

Any help? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Seems you must use

```
<item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.MyApp.ActionBar</item>
```

Here is solved the similiar problem:
[Action Bar Sherlock 4 title text colour - where am I going wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10466796/action-bar-sherlock-4-title-text-colour-where-am-i-going-wrong)

Comment: But thats WITH sherlock. I want to do it without that.

Comment: it is also will work with android action bar. look at the bottom here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html