# How i change the color of the text in a actionbarsherlock?

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I want to know how to change the color of the title and subititle of the tab in a actionbarscherlock. now the color's text is white i want to change this. thank's to all.

this is my style code:

```
<style name="Theme.Example" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/selectable_background_example</item>
    <item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu.Example</item>
    <item name="dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListView.Example</item>
    <item name="actionBarTabStyle">@style/ActionBarTabStyle.Example</item>
    <item name="actionDropDownStyle">@style/DropDownNav.Example</item>
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar.Solid.Example</item>
    <item name="actionModeBackground">@drawable/cab_background_top_example</item>
    <item name="actionModeSplitBackground">@drawable/cab_background_bottom_example</item>
    <item name="actionModeCloseButtonStyle">@style/ActionButton.CloseMode.Example</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/red</item>




            <!-- Light.DarkActionBar specific -->
    <item name="actionBarWidgetTheme">@style/Theme.Example.Widget</item>

</style>




    <style name="Skoletube.Tab.Text" parent="Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar.TabText">
<item name="android:textAppearance">@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium</item>
<item name="android:textColor">@android:color/black</item>
```

```
<style name="ActionBar.Solid.Example" parent="@style/Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="background">@drawable/ab_solid_example</item>
    <item name="backgroundStacked">@drawable/ab_stacked_solid_example</item>
    <item name="backgroundSplit">@drawable/ab_bottom_solid_example</item>
    <item name="progressBarStyle">@style/ProgressBar.Example</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBar.Transparent.Example" parent="@style/Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar">
    <item name="background">@drawable/ab_transparent_example</item>
    <item name="progressBarStyle">@style/ProgressBar.Example</item>
</style>

<style name="PopupMenu.Example" parent="@style/Widget.Sherlock.ListPopupWindow">    
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/menu_dropdown_panel_example</item>
</style>

<style name="DropDownListView.Example" parent="@style/Widget.Sherlock.ListView.DropDown">
    <item name="android:listSelector">@drawable/selectable_background_example</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBarTabStyle.Example" parent="@style/Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar.TabView">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/tab_indicator_ab_example</item>
</style>

<style name="DropDownNav.Example" parent="@style/Widget.Sherlock.Spinner.DropDown.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/spinner_background_ab_example</item>
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/menu_dropdown_panel_example</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownSelector">@drawable/selectable_background_example</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/red</item>
</style>

<style name="ProgressBar.Example" parent="@style/Widget.Sherlock.ProgressBar.Horizontal">
    <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/progress_horizontal_example</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionButton.CloseMode.Example" parent="@style/Widget.Sherlock.ActionButton.CloseMode">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/btn_cab_done_example</item>
</style>

<!-- this style is only referenced in a Light.DarkActionBar based theme -->
<style name="Theme.Example.Widget" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock">
    <item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu.Example</item>
    <item name="dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListView.Example</item>
</style>
```

it does not give me errors but I don't change the text colors

Comment: possible duplicate of [Action Bar Sherlock 4 title text colour - where am I going wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10466796/action-bar-sherlock-4-title-text-colour-where-am-i-going-wrong)

Comment: See also: http://actionbarsherlock.com/theming.html

Answer (score 0):

Replace your `Theme.Example` with this one and your `Skoletube.Tab.Text` with `TabText`:

```
<style name="Theme.Example" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/selectable_background_example</item>
    <item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu.Example</item>
    <item name="dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListView.Example</item>
    <item name="actionBarTabStyle">@style/ActionBarTabStyle.Example</item>
    <item name="actionDropDownStyle">@style/DropDownNav.Example</item>
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar.Solid.Example</item>
    <item name="actionModeBackground">@drawable/cab_background_top_example</item>
    <item name="actionModeSplitBackground">@drawable/cab_background_bottom_example</item>
    <item name="actionModeCloseButtonStyle">@style/ActionButton.CloseMode.Example</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/red</item>

            <!-- Light.DarkActionBar specific -->
    <item name="actionBarWidgetTheme">@style/Theme.Example.Widget</item>

    <item name="actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/TabText</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/TabText</item>

</style>

<style name="Theme.Example.TabText" parent="Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar.TabText">
 <item name="android:textAppearance">@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium</item>
 <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/black</item>
</style>
```

EDIT: 
this is the proper way of doing something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<style name="YOURTHEME" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light">
<item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/YOURTHEME.ActionBarStyle</item>
<item name="actionBarStyle">@style/YOURTHEME.ActionBarStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="YOURTHEME.ActionBarStyle" parent="Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar">
<item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/YOURTHEME.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
<item name="titleTextStyle">@style/YOURTHEME.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="YOURTHEME.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle" parent="TextAppearance.Sherlock.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
<item name="android:textColor">@color/YOUR_COLOR</item>
<item name="textColor">@color/YOUR_COLOR</item>
<item name="android:textSize">@dimension/MEDIUM_TEXT</item>
<item name="textSize">@dimension/MEDIUM_TEXT</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

Comment: can you put a screen capture?

Comment: i updated the answer, take a look to see if it works.

Comment: i didn't put a screen capture because i don't have a 10 of reputation.
however don't work equally, the error is on "@style/Skoletube.Tab.Text"

Comment: Have you deleted this?  `<style name="Skoletube.Tab.Text" parent="Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar.TabText">
<item name="android:textAppearance">@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium</item>
<item name="android:textColor">@android:color/black</item>`   In the code that you posted it doesn't have a close style like this: `</style>`

Comment: I have deleted Skoletube.Tab.Text for error, i put them now in the code but it not work equally

Comment: @GiacomoJackMenestò I am going to edit (again) my answer and put the code and you just have to copy paste!

Comment: what is the error? you have to give more information so that i can help you.

Comment: If you have an error at this line: `<item name="android:actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/TabText</item>` just remove it!

Comment: i have sended the image.